# Delete tag effiency

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There is a tag named effiency (see https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effiency )

Delete it, yes?

Answer (score 7):

The tag has been removed from the post, and will disappear shortly.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of it! :-)